# Access all Eventbrite events via API

Tags: eventbrite

I read this information, but if we want to allow our users to access/view/discover all the Eventbrite events (that are in Canada), how would we go about this?

http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/widgets/#list

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `event_search` call.  You can see an example of how do to that in the Javascript library here:

https://github.com/ryanjarvinen/Eventbrite.jquery.js#-event_search-

You will simply need to pass the desired arguments to the search API:

http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_search/